# Как определить формат содержимого бинарного файла

Tags: java, android

Есть куча бинарных файлов, нужно узнать формат содержимого каждого из них. Всего в этой куче есть два формата, которые нужно определять: JPEG и MP4 и в зависимости от того какой формат, надо использовать либо VideoView, либо ImageView. Смотрел решение где предлагали смотреть первые 8 бит, но я открываю этот бинарный файл и там эти биты разные даже у одинаковых форматов, если 100 процентный способ определения? Обрабатывать на исключении думаю не правильно (если я попытаюсь запихнуть картинку в VideoView вылезет ошибка)

Comment: Слишком общий вопрос. Некоторые форматы не имеют четкой сигнатуры, некоторые имеют сигнатуру в 64 бита, а не 8. Некоторые - 32 бита и так далее.

Comment: Не знал про сигнатуры) Ладно, сейчас подкорректирую вопрос

Comment: Вам нужен 100%-способ определения формата?

Comment: @hedgehogues Угум

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Сигнатура MP4](http://www.file-recovery.com/mp4-signature-format.htm) 
[Сигнатура JPEG](http://www.file-recovery.com/jpg-signature-format.htm) 
Ну в общем для JPEG надо смотреть первые 2 байта, у jpeg они всегда одинаковые ( 0xFF, 0xD8).
для MP4 надо смотреть c 5ого по 8ой байт. Они должны равняться 0x66, 0x74, 0x79, 0x34

Answer (score 2):

JPEG должен начинаться с 2 байтов 0xFF, 0xD8, а заканчиваться 0xFF, 0xD9. Но вроде в начале может быть произвольное число 0xFF.